# Node.js ReferenceError

Tags: node.js

This is my first go at NodeJS. I've installed it successfully on an instance at DigitalOcean.

I have the following helloworld.js

```
require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8888);console.log('Hello world');
```

When I run it via "node helloworld.js", I get the following error:

```
/home/jason/helloworld.js:4
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
^
ReferenceError: http is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jason/helloworld.js:4:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:901:3
jason@do:~$
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The error message contains the string `http`, but it's not in the program you posted. Can you copy and paste your actual program?

Comment: please post full program , as I do not see the Content Type header line complete

Comment: I'm using this tutorial: http://www.nodebeginner.org/#hello-world

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`require()` doesn't work like `#include` or `import` does in other languages.

require() returns a reference to the resolved module. That reference must be assigned to a variable.

```
var http = require('http'); //the variable doesn't necessarily have to be named http
http.createServer(function(req, res) {});
```

Or

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly states, there is no `re` function.

Do you mean `require`?

Comment: Ah that's embarrassing. I've done that but am still getting a similar error (updated in OP).

Comment: @JasonStockman: `require()` _returns_ an object from the module you're importing.  It doesn't create a variable for you; you need to use the return value.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same problem and I have tried this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   response.end('Server started\n');
}).listen(8081);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

May be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I tried
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

response.end('Server started\n');
}).listen(8081);

console.log('Server running at [http://127.0.0.1:8081/'](http://127.0.0.1:8081/%27));

and it worked for me.